# Equality of Functions as Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, constraints, optimal-transport

On page 8 of [1], at the start of the proof of well defined-ness, Chodosh says "if $\phi_{12}(x_{1},x_{2}) + \phi_{23}(x_{2},x_{3}) = \tilde\phi_{12}(x_{1},x_{2}) + \tilde\phi_{23}(x_{2},x_{3})$ **as functions**, then
$$\phi_{12}(x_{1},x_{2}) - \tilde\phi_{12}(x_{1},x_{2}) = \tilde\phi_{23}(x_{2},x_{3}) - \phi_{23}(x_{2},x_{3})$$ 
which shows that both sides are functions of $x_{2}$ only."

What does the "as functions" mean? Also, it is not obvious to me how both sides are functions of $x_{2}$.

Reference:
[1] O. Chodosh (2012) Optimal Transport and Ricci Curvature: Wasserstein Space Over the Interval. arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.2883

Comment: I believe it most likely means that the equality holds for all values of $x_1,x_2,x_3,$ as opposed to holding at a particular choice of $x_1,x_2,x_3.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the signs problem in the first out-of-text formula is cured, the left hand side does not depend on $x_3$ thus it is the same for the right and vice-versa for $x_1$.